# Directory.Move isn't trying the correct folder

Tags: vb.net, directory, move, .net

I have made some code intended to sort all my movies on my PC into subfolders for each letter of the alphabet (e.g. "An Example" would go in a subfolder containing only movies which start with the letter "A".

The code I've written looks to me like it should work without problems, although for some reason this code:

```
'Declarations
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\Vuze Downloads\Movies\.CAMS")
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\Vuze Downloads\Movies\.TS")
Dim TS As String = "D:\Vuze Downloads\Movies\.TS\"
Dim CAM As String = "D:\Vuze Downloads\Movies\.CAMS\"
Dim mainFolder As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("D:\Vuze Downloads\Movies\")

For Each f As System.IO.DirectoryInfo In mainFolder.GetDirectories()
    If Not UCase(f.ToString).Contains("(CAM)") And UCase(f.ToString).Contains("(TS)") Then
        System.IO.Directory.Move(f.ToString, mainFolder.Name & UCase(Left(f.Name, 1)) & "\" & f.Name)
    ElseIf UCase(f.Name.ToString).Contains("(CAM)") And Not UCase(f.Name.ToString).Contains("(TS)") Then
        System.IO.Directory.Move(f.ToString, CAM.ToString & UCase(Mid(f.Name, 5)) & "\" & f.Name.Substring(5))
    ElseIf UCase(f.Name.ToString).Contains("(TS)") And Not UCase(f.Name.ToString).Contains("(CAM)") Then
        System.IO.Directory.Move(f.ToString, TS.ToString & UCase(Mid(f.Name, 6)) & "\" & f.Name.Substring(6))
    End If
Next
```

Keeps throwing a exception at this line:

```
System.IO.Directory.Move(f.ToString, CAM.ToString & UCase(Mid(f.Name, 5)) & "\" & f.Name.Substring(5))
```

This is the exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in
 mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 
'D:\Users\Yorrick\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\filmsort\filmsort\bin\Debug\(CAM)The Internship'.
```

As indicated by the declarations above, I have no idea how or why this code is trying to access that folder.

If anyone could take a look and hopefully spot the mistake I've made, that would be very much be appreciated.

Edit:

Having fixed the above problem, I encountered a new one.
Using the code below, I now get the same exception, except this time additional information says "Could not find a part of the path." All my variables seem to be correct while debugging, so I seriously can't see why this isn't working.

Note: The commented line is something I tried, which gives me the `System.IO.IOException: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.`

Code:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\Vuze Downloads\Movies\.CAMS")
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\Vuze Downloads\Movies\.TS")
Dim TS As String = "D:\Vuze Downloads\Movies\.TS\"
Dim CAM As String = "D:\Vuze Downloads\Movies\.CAMS\"
Dim mainFolder As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("D:\Vuze Downloads\Movies\")

For Each f As System.IO.DirectoryInfo In mainFolder.GetDirectories()
    If Not UCase(f.ToString).Contains("(CAM)") And UCase(f.ToString).Contains("(TS)") Then
        System.IO.Directory.Move(f.FullName, mainFolder.FullName & UCase(Left(f.Name, 1)) & "\" & f.Name)
    ElseIf UCase(f.Name.ToString).Contains("(CAM)") And Not UCase(f.Name.ToString).Contains("(TS)") Then
        'System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(CAM & UCase(Mid(f.Name, 6)) & "\" & f.Name.Substring(6))
        System.IO.Directory.Move(f.FullName, CAM & UCase(Mid(f.Name, 6)) & "\" & f.Name.Substring(6))
    ElseIf UCase(f.Name.ToString).Contains("(TS)") And Not UCase(f.Name.ToString).Contains("(CAM)") Then
        System.IO.Directory.Move(f.FullName, TS.ToString & UCase(Mid(f.Name, 5)) & "\" & f.Name.Substring(5))
    End If
Next
```

Comment: First thing i notice is the use of `UCase` which really is a old vb6 legacy function and you should use `.ToUpper.Contains()` instead, though thats just nitpicking, nothing jumping out at me so i'll try to reproduce this in order to find the cause.

Comment: Good point, I seem to keep using UCase even though I keep being told it's outdated, but hey, it has the exact same functionality so I guess there's no problem in using it, right? :P Either way, in the answers there's already a listed reason as to why it's acting up, fixed that problem, but now it can't find a part of a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you don't specify a full path name, like "c:\foo\bar", but a relative path name, like "bar".  Relative path names are turned into full ones by prepending Environment.CurrentDirectory.  Which by default is the build directory of your project.

This happened because you used DirectoryInfo.Name.  Which is "bar" for a directory whose path is c:\foo\bar.  You must use the FullName property instead.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you're suggesting I use `System.IO.Directory.Move(f.FullName, CAM & UCase(Mid(f.Name, 6)) & "\" & f.Name.Substring(6))`, correct? If so, for some reason that gives me another exception, saying it can not find part of the path (it doesn't specify which path though)

Comment: I saw you use mainFolder.Name, that should be mainFolder.FullName.  The rest makes my eyes bleed.  Debug this by assigning the string to a local variable so you can see it.  And always favor the Path.Combine() method to build path strings.

Comment: Yeh I haven't edited that yet, but it's still giving me the error I just mentioned though

Answer (score 0):

I just rewrote it a bit, i think that should suffice for your purpose.

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\Vuze Downloads\Movies\.CAMS")
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\Vuze Downloads\Movies\.TS")
Dim TS As String = "D:\Vuze Downloads\Movies\.TS\"
Dim CAM As String = "D:\Vuze Downloads\Movies\.CAMS\"
Dim mainFolder As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("D:\Vuze Downloads\Movies\")

For Each f As System.IO.DirectoryInfo In mainFolder.GetDirectories()
    If f.Name.ToUpper.Contains("(TS)") Then
        System.IO.Directory.Move(f.FullName, System.IO.Path.Combine(TS, f.Name))
    ElseIf f.Name.ToUpper.Contains("(CAM)") Then
        System.IO.Directory.Move(f.FullName, System.IO.Path.Combine(CAM, f.Name))
    End If
Next
```